# UnsatisfiedLinkError when starting a K8S pod based on a Ballerina Service

Tags: kubernetes, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I'm trying to start a K8S pod based on a Ballerina service and I'm getting the following error

> error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError {"message":"failed to load the required native library","cause":error("java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",message="Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64, netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora, netty_tcnative_x86_64, netty_tcnative]")}

The runtime is ballerina/jvm-runtime:1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The issue often occurs when the file system is readonly. Netty needs the `/tmp` directory to be writable.

One possible solution for this is, mounting an empty directory to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this could be due to missing [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) dependency (required by [netty](https://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html#using-the-linux-native-transport) for the underlying native transport implementation) in your base image. (e.g. `alphine linux` base image does not contain `glibc` as per the [alphine linux documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux).)

Therefore, this can be solved by switching to any base image which comes with the aforementioned dependency by-default.

Related issues and discussions can be found in [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-library/issues/2803) and [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/11701).